# Select a file from Multiple Files Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory, azure-files

I have multiple files in FTP and I need to select on a daily basis as my Data Source the last one.

clients_08082022.csv

clients_09082022.csv

clients_10082022.csv

clients_11082022.csv

clients_12082022.csv

clients_13082022.csv

If I would have the file from today (14082022), the code would be:

```
  @{concat('clients_',convertFromUtc(utcnow(), 'Romance Standard Ti-me','yyyyMMdd'),'_*.csv')}
```

But I need to subtract one day from today's day. I tried the function addDays and subtractFromTime, but they do not work.

```
@{concat(‘clients_’,convertFromUtc(addDays(utcnow(),-1),'Romance Stan-dard Time','ddMMyyyy'),'.csv')}

@{concat(‘clients_',convertFromUtc(subtractFromTime(utcnow(),1,'Day'),'Romance Standard Time','ddMMyyyy'),'.csv')}
```

I have an error when I want to visualise the dataset.
[image]

Comment: I have an error: The function convertFromUtc is currently not supported for schema operations.

Comment: Can you please edit and add pipeline image with error .

Comment: I have just atatched the image with the error. It occurs only when I am trying to preview the dataset

Comment: In which activity are you using the provided dynamic content

Comment: I am using it in Copy Data